# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils

Tags: here-api

I just upgraded my HERE Android SDK Premium to 3.12 and it keeps crashing at start with the following exception:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-07-25 13:07:46.822 13396-13396/com.here.rcp.htcontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.here.rcp.htcontrol, PID: 13396
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils: com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils$LegacyIds com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils.fetchLegacyIds(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) failed to verify: com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils$LegacyIds com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils.fetchLegacyIds(android.content.Context, java.lang.String): [0x31] 'this' arg must be initialized (declaration of 'com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils' appears in /data/app/com.here.rcp.htcontrol-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes2.dex)
        at com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacUtils.fetchLegacyIds(HacUtils.java:1)
        at com.here.sdk.hacwrapper.HacAnalytics.initialize(HacAnalytics.java:4)
        at com.nokia.maps.Vb.a(AnalyticsTrackerExternal.java:32)
        at com.nokia.maps._a.a(Analytics.java:5)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$h.a(MapsEngine.java:89)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$h.onPostExecute(MapsEngine.java:1)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HERE SDK Version: 3.12.4.93
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$l.uncaughtException(MapsEngine.java:4)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
```

The credentials and the package are still the same.

I already changed my old MapFragment to the more recent SupportMapFragment class.

Comment: How you initialise HacUtils ? This could be because your older HacUtils dependencies is being referenced and there are changes related to classes which cause the "VerifyError"

Comment: The HacUtils is initialized by some internal SDK calls I don't have access to. Okay, let me try to clean up all caches and previous builds, maybe I messed up something. Thank you!

Comment: We have the same issue. We use HERE map in a separate module. And it works well when we use it in a sample project. 
But we have a crash, when we connect it to our real project. We have no idea what the reason is.
@HEREDeveloperSupport could you please help us with the problem above

Comment: Guys, is it possible to provide sample app where the issue is reproducible? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a sample app handy anymore but we figured out that our issue was caused by the New Relic gradle plugin that does insert some code into compiled classes. When not using the New Relic gradle plugin, everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out that our issue was caused by the New Relic gradle plugin that does insert some code into compiled classes. When not using the New Relic gradle plugin, everything was fine.

We basically removed:

```
classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.18.1"
```

From the root gradle.

And we stopped using using the New Relic agent as a consequence:

```
implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.18.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to newrelic android-agent version 5.24+ should solve the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I had to disable new relic from the project to get rid of this error. I was using new relic version 5.19.1